# Application begin-work action

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, terminology, word-in-context

In IT do all these words: launch, start, execute, and run have the same meaning? Have they at least a slight difference between them?

- Execute/launch/start/run Adobe Photoshop.

As far as I know they do mean the same thing but I want to be plain sure.

Comment: We generally don't say execute Adobe Photoshop, but we do say execute a piece of code, or a batch file.

Comment: I'd suggest that you're executing photoshop.exe, but you're launching/starting/running Adobe Photoshop.  And if you leave it open, then five minutes later you're still running Adobe Photoshop, whereas you're no longer launching or starting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those words all have to do with a process, they all contain the idea of "starting".

**Execute** stands out as different from the others.

We *execute* that which has a relatively narrow purpose or goal and runs under its own steam, so to speak, with minimal or no user interaction once it has been initiated.

We execute executables (commands, routines, programs, procedures) and they perform a task or a series of tasks.

We wouldn't "execute" a word processing program, say, or a spreadsheet, since many different things can be accomplished with these "applications" (the task is not pre-defined) and they require constant user interaction.